# how to not capture a page title within a loop using selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to loop through the elements and clicking on each of the links. I need to assert the actual title and the expected title ( from the list). 3 links open in a parent window and 2 in a child window. When I close the child window and come back to parent window to capture the title of the next child window, it captures the parent title as well. And the assertion fails because of that. I wanted to know if there is a way where I can code a way to not capture the parent window title when revisiting for clicking on the next link that would open a child window.
Sorry I don't know how best to put this in words:
Open the below screenshot explains:

Thanks in Advance for any help and guidance.
BM

This is my code

```java
for (WebElement lElement : navList) {
                links.contains(lElement.getAttribute("data-label"));
                base.getTestCase().log(Status.INFO, "SC Portal contains link - " + lElement.getAttribute("data-label"));
                String link = lElement.getText();
                String expectedTitle = links.get(counter);
                lElement.click();
                String actualParentTitle = webDriver.getTitle();
                System.out.println(actualParentTitle + ":" + expectedTitle);
                // Navigating between the tabs to get the page titles
                String parent = webDriver.getWindowHandle();
                Set<String> s = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
                //String expectedTitle = links.get(counter);
                Iterator<String> I1 = s.iterator();
                while (I1.hasNext()) {
                    String child_window = I1.next();
                    if (!parent.equals(child_window)) {
                        webDriver.switchTo().window(child_window);
                        // waitForPageLoad(30);
                        String actualChildTitle = webDriver.switchTo().window(child_window).getTitle();
                        System.out.println(actualChildTitle + ":" + expectedTitle);
                        Assert.assertTrue(actualChildTitle.contains(expectedTitle));
                        webDriver.close();
                        webDriver.switchTo().window(parent);
                    }
```

[image]

I dont want to capture the ones marked X.

Comment: A small thing I have observed here is, that Selenium will be active in the child window and you are directly closing the child window, but Selenium remains in the child window because, through the code level, you didn't switch to another child window.                      My suggestion is: whatever your activity in each child window complete it first by switching to other windows, and once all your activity is completed that time you close the browser.

Comment: Thanks Bhairu. That is right and I got the issue resolved. I had to ignore the parent window being captured more than once.